# I can't call the .show() function after I crop an image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, crop, show

I am trying to crop an image here, however every time when I run .show() on the cropped image, it is giving me an error.

Using Python 3.9.1 and Pillow 8.0

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('image.PNG')
print (image.size)
width, height = image.size

print (width)
print (height)

newWidth = int(width/2)
newHeight = int(height/2)

print (newWidth)
print (newHeight)

img = image.crop((newWidth,newHeight,newWidth,newHeight))

img.show()
```

This is how the error looks like

[image: Error Code]

Comment: Pls copy the error code and paste it here don't paste an image

Comment: The image returned from `crop()` is likely no good because the arguments you passed it are incorrect. See the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.crop). The box argument is supposed to be `(left, upper, right, lower)` which is not what you're passing — what you have defines a rectangle of zero width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approch using `cv2`

```
import cv2
img=cv2.imread("image.PNG")
new_height=int(img.shape[0]/2)
new_width=int(img.shape[1]/2)
img=img[0:new_height,0:new_width] #cropping image
cv2.imshow("cropped_image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

That must help if you want to cut a center of image. Problem was in arguments of CROP function. You should fill in it with coordinations of corners new image. Write on english is hard for me, so ask me, if you don't understand something

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open(r'image.png')
print(image.size)
width, height = image.size

print(width)
print(height)

newWidth = int(width / 2)
newHeight = int(height / 2)

print(newWidth)
print(newHeight)

left = width - newWidth // 2
upper = height - newHeight // 2
right = left + newWidth
lower = upper + newHeight

img = image.crop((left, upper, right, lower))

img.show()
```